# After upgrade to Joomla 3.6, new saved articles are on the bottom of the articles list

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, update, upgrade

Yesterday I upgraded Joomla to the new 3.6 version and I published an article which didn't show up on my page. I've browsed through the articles, and the newly published article was at the bottom of that list. How can I save the article to be ordered by published date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug (some claim it's a feature) and is currently being sorted out here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/11103

I think there will be a Joomla 3.6.1 very soon.